# Tree View Context Menu - Pass selected item to command?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview

I'm wondering how to pass the selected item to a command from a treeview / HierarchicalDataTemplate ?

Here is the code that I have so far, it displays the context menu but I haven't bound the commands to it yet. The command binding is the easy part, but how do I tell which node it came from ?

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
    DataType="{x:Type viewModel:UsersViewModel}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" Margin="3,0" Source="Images\Region.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Edit" />
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete"/>
                     </ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `{Binding}` should be the whole item.

(To pass it to the `Command` bind the `CommandParameter`, in `Execute` and `CanExecute` it will become the method parameter (which you then need to cast to your item-type))

Comment: Could you provide a sample ? I'm not able to get it to work. But from my research I see that this is the correct way to do it. I'll mark as answered for now.

Comment: @BatMasterson: [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914867/why-cant-i-use-datacontext-binding-for-my-context-menu/6914964#6914964), it should clear the problem you probably have.