# WPF: Unable to access static resource from child control

Tags: wpf, binding, staticresource

I cannot find out how to access my Window.Resources from inside a child control's Resource section.  I have a DataTemplate being defined in the child control, and want that DataTemplate to bind to an ICommand on my view model (defined in Window.Resources)

*EDIT:*  I added my `RadPaneGroup` code to the Main Window XAML.  This is where I instantiate the `ProjectsViewModel` object.  The `ProjectsView` control contained in the `RadDocumentPane` is the Child Control I have listed below.

**Main Window**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <viewModels:ProjectsViewModel x:Key="ProjectsViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<telerik:RadDocking HasDocumentHost="False" >
    <telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        <telerik:RadPaneGroup DataContext="{StaticResource ProjectsViewModel}">
            <telerik:RadDocumentPane Header="Projects">
                <views:ProjectsView/>
            </telerik:RadDocumentPane>
        </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
    </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
    ...
```

**Child Control**

```
<Control.Resources>
    <!--Data template for the Task object-->
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type models:Task}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Foreground="Red" 
                       FontSize="16" FontFamily="Verdana" />
            <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
                <telerik:RadContextMenu >
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem Header="New Project" 
                            Command="{Binding NewProjectCommand}"/>
                </telerik:RadContextMenu>
            </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The binding on the above XAML is trying to bind to the Task object.  However, my ICommand is located in the ViewModel (ProjectsViewModel).  I've tried to change the binding to `Command="{Binding NewProjectCommand, Source={StaticResource ProjectsViewModel}}` but this throws an exception.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your _ChildControl_ an `UserControl` or a `CustomControl`?

Comment: My control is s UserControl - basically holds a TreeView for one of the panes in my main window.

Comment: Made an edit to show how the ProjectsViewModel is being instantiated in XAML.

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown?

Answer (score 4):

Your DataTemplate looks like it is being used in an ItemsControl (e.g. a ListBox), so as you say `Command="{Binding NewProjectCommand}"` will be trying to bind to a property of the `Task` type, whereas you really want to bind to a property of the parent container. You therefore need to use a RelativeSource binding, something like:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.NewProjectCommand, RelativeSource=
         {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type views:ProjectsView}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a similar approach to the question at [Why can't I use DataContext={Binding} for my context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914867/why-cant-i-use-datacontext-binding-for-my-context-menu) to fix this.

The basic reason this may not be working is that the ContextMenu is technically a separate window, so it has it's own visual tree and may not be included in the logical tree of the document pane.  As a result, it doesn't know how to find the resource from the containing view.

```
 DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.NewProjectCommand,
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadContextMenu}}}"
```